# How can I approximately copy a UV map?

Tags: uv, 3d-printing

Background: I wanted to try 3D-printing models from video games. So when I had some spare time I googled a bit, and managed to extract the model I wanted from the game. Unfortunately, it still had tons of nonmanifold edges (which break the printing process). Luckily i found a tool that was able to modify the model enough that it still looks pretty close to the original but has 0 nonmanifold-edges.

But now I have a problem: While converting, the second model lost its texture/UV map, which I need. It has obviously a different amount of verts and faces, so I can't just copy the original UV map and textures. And what Blender does with automatic unwrapping looks nothing like the original UV map at all. So, my question is:

**Can I get Blender to try and create a UV map on my second model that is as close to the original UV map from another model as possible?**

I'm willing to correct a couple of parts in a UV map manually, but I don't want to manually unwrap a UV map from a model with thousands of faces. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I assume you want the UVs to use texture coordinates. What you could do, is unwrap the new model in whatever way, then back the textures from the original to the new UVs.

Comment: @OmarAhmad I'm honestly not sure what you mean by that... Move the new map so it resembles the old one as closely as possible? Since the faces in the UV map need to correspond to the ones on the model I can't just use any way of unwrapping, AFAIK

Comment: I mean to re-bake the textures to a new UV layout. Are you familiar with texture baking?

Comment: @OmarAhmad Oh, _baking_. That c confusee me :D I have a general idea of what it's for and what it does, yes. But apart from some tinkering a year ago or so I don't have much experience with 3D modelling, so it'll require some googling to actually try your idea.